# How to fill object with DateTime from datatable in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, datatable

I am currently creating a website which is using Highcharts and ASP.NET MVC3 (C#).

I have already filled a datatable within C# with the relevant data from a MySQL database:

[Properties http://imageshack.com/a/img17/1474/z2cy.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img17/1474/z2cy.png)

To connect the data with the Highcharts-framework, it is necessary to create an object which looks like this:

```
object[,] seriesData = { { new DateTime(year1int, month1int, day1int, hour1int, minute1int, second1int), temperatur1int }, { new DateTime(year2int, month2int, day2int, hour2int, minute2int, second2int), temperatur2int }, { new DateTime(year3int, month3int, day3int, hour3int, minute3int, second3int), temperatur3int } };
```

To test my code, I´ve read some values manually:

```
object day1 = datatable.Rows[0]["DAY"];
object month1 = datatable.Rows[0]["MONTH"];
object year1 = datatable.Rows[0]["YEAR"];
object hour1 = datatable.Rows[0]["HOUR"];
object minute1 = datatable.Rows[0]["MINUTE"];
object second1 = datatable.Rows[0]["SECOND"];
object temperatur1 = datatable.Rows[0]["temperatur"];

int day1int = Convert.ToInt16(day1);
int month1int = Convert.ToInt16(month1);
int year1int = Convert.ToInt16(year1);
int hour1int = Convert.ToInt16(hour1);
int minute1int = Convert.ToInt16(minute1);
int second1int = Convert.ToInt16(second1);
int temperatur1int = Convert.ToInt16(temperatur1);
```

Since there are >100 rows, it is necessary to create a loop which is reading the values from the datatable and writing them into the array. It is my first C#-project and on this point I have no idea how to continue and create the loop-function :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to create JSON if you want to plot in highcharts in real time. And call it using Ajax.

Well, look at [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535536/live-multiple-series-with-highchart)

I was facing the similar problem. I have posted my entire code along with c#(server side) then how to create json and how to call it using Ajax in javascript.

Comment: As far as I can see, you are using regular time intervals. For my purpose it is necessery to use irregular times like in the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/