# How do i put dynamic values inside Highchart.js data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, highcharts

I am using codeigniter, I use below code to query dynamic values based on the selection in the dropdown box.

```
$("#month").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        data : 'month='+ $(this).val() + '&year='+$('#year').val(),
        url : '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/suggestion/processReportBreakdown";?>',
        success : function(data){
            $('#section').html(data); //<---- i need to print html data
        }
    });
});

$("#year").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        data : 'month='+ $(this).val() + '&year='+$('#year').val(),
        url : '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/suggestion/processReportBreakdown";?>',
        success : function(data){
            $('#section').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

the processReportBreakdown() goes like this:

```
public function processReportBreakdown()
{
    $month              = $this->input->post('month');
    $year               = $this->input->post('year');
    $data['query']  =   $this->suggestion->breakDownReport($month, $year);

    $data['totalBreakdown'] = $this->suggestion->getAllRowsBreakDownReport($month, $year);
    $total = $data['totalBreakdown']-1;

    $i = 0;

    foreach($data['query'] as $row)
    {

        if($i != $total)
        {
            echo "'".$row->countReport."',";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "'".$row->countReport."'";
        }

        $i++;

    }

}
```

Now I want to get the response of ajax POST and print it inside highchart data... so that everytime that the dropdown changes, the chart also changes in accordance with the values being passed by ajax POST. What could be the proper way of doing this?

Comment: How your json looks like?

Comment: processBreakDown() returns something like: '30','21','5','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1'

Comment: I am not familiar with php but for highchartd your json should be an array without quates. [30,21,5,0,0,0.....]

Comment: ok i already managed to convert to json.. it looks like this now: [30,21,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

Comment: Chk the links in my answer and use that approach

Comment: Have you tried to return json in php and then load it in highcharts by jquery ?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of example available on the highcharts.com

just look at this link [Live Server](http://www.highcharts.com/studies/live-server.htm)

It will be use full for you else for java script you can consider this answer as well 
[Live Multiple Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535536/live-multiple-series-with-highchart)

Comment: Was it useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example straight from [creating highchart with ajax json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236113/creating-highchart-with-ajax-json-data) I see you can't figure out how to use highchart with ajax

```
function visitorData (data) {
   $('#chart1').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Average Visitors'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of visitors'
        }
    },
    series: data,
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
    url: '/visitdata',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        visitorData(data);
    }
  });
 });
```

Sample php codeigniter code to return json output more at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/output.html

```
$this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar')));
```

I don't know what is the purpose of this code

```
foreach($data['query'] as $row)
{

    if($i != $total)
    {
        echo "'".$row->countReport."',";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "'".$row->countReport."'";
    }

    $i++;

}
```

you are echoing here the output is html so collect all the data and output it as json

Comment: how do i get the data in the processBreakDown() function?